# OpenSSL под Windows (используя g++ и MSYS2) - не могу собрать проект

Tags: c++, windows, smtp, openssl, msys2

Господа, я пытаюсь из программы на C++ отправить письмо по SMTP через сервер gmail.com.

Беру очень старый и очень известный [проект](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98355/SMTP-Client-with-SSL-TLS)

В нём все хорошо и понятно, но это проект под Visual Studio и он 32-битный. И библиотеки (и инклуды от openssl) "вшиты" прямо в проект.

Я пытаюсь собрать его с использованием свеженькой openssl, установив её через MSYS2 командой `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl`

Проверяю: команда `pacman -Q | grep ssl` выводит

```
    libopenssl 1.1.1.g-3
    mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl 1.1.1.g-1
    openssl 1.1.1.g-3
```

и по пути `C:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\include` есть директория `openssl` со всеми *.h - файлами.

Захожу по [ссылке](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl), описывающий этот package, вижу там следующие бинарные файлы (то есть, не-инкулуды, не - доки и не-маны):

```
    /mingw64/bin/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
    /mingw64/bin/libssl-1_1-x64.dll
    /mingw64/bin/openssl.exe
    /mingw64/lib/engines-1_1/capi.dll
    /mingw64/lib/engines-1_1/padlock.dll
    /mingw64/lib/libcrypto.a
    /mingw64/lib/libcrypto.dll.a
    /mingw64/lib/libssl.a
    /mingw64/lib/libssl.dll.a
    /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
    /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
    /mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/openssl.pc
```

Итак, у меня есть директория с проектом, в ней есть файл main.cpp, я поставил все необходимые зависимости, пишу в консоли, запущенной в этой директории `g++ -std=c++17 -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin -lssl-1_1-x64 -lcrypto-1_1-x64 -IC:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\include main.cpp -o main.exe` и получаю большой набор ошибок линкера, который начинается так:

```
    C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Konst\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF1y7VW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `CSmtp::CSmtp()'
    C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Konst\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF1y7VW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `CSmtp::SetSMTPServer(char const*, unsigned short, bool)'
    C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Konst\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF1y7VW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `CSmtp::SetLogin(char const*)'
    C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Konst\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF1y7VW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `CSmtp::SetPassword(char const*)'
    C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Konst\AppData\Local\Temp\ccF1y7VW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x8f): undefined reference to `CSmtp::SetSenderName(char const*)'
```

Точно такой же набор ошибок я получаю, если я вообще не указываю библиотек.

и при сборке командой

```
    g++ -std=c++17 -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/lib -lssl -lcrypto -IC:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\include main.cpp -o main.exe
```

или командой

```
   g++ -std=c++17 -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/lib -llibssl -llibcrypto -IC:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\include main.cpp -o main.exe
```

-набор ошибок не меняется.

Значит, я что то не так указываю в ключах -l или -L ?

В исходном проекте используются только 2 библиотеки, называются libeay32.lib и ssleay32.lib.

Может быть, кто то знает, какие их аналоги надо указать при сборке проекта в 64-битной версии?

Спасибо.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар подсказывает мне, что это ошибки из-за кусков вашего кода, который вы не собираете и не линкуете в проекте. Неужели там весь код, включая определения CSmtp::CSmtp, в одном main.cpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Господа,

спасибо всем, кто обратил внимание на мой вопрос.

Фактически, на мой вопрос в комментариях ответил  **HolyBlackCat**, который помогает мне уже не в первый раз.

И ответ на это вопрос хорош не только тем, что отвечает "как собрать конкретную программу", но и тем, что описывает общий способ решать такие проблемы.

Краткое содержание: мне понадобилось понять, какие ошибки я совершаю, когда формирую строку запуска компилятора. Затем мне понадобилось научиться пользоваться утилитой pkg-config и просто копировать ключи, которые подсказывает эта утилита, в команду запуска компилятора. И как вишенка на торте - я наконец то, через 3 года мучений научился статически линковаться в windows.

Мои шаги были следующими:

1. упростить задачу до невозможности.

Давайте не будем отправлять email, это сложно, к тому же кто их читает сейчас... Давайте просто посчитаем хэш SHA1

Гуглим [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918676/generate-sha-hash-in-c-using-openssl-library)

Исправляем в примере ошибку, заменив `SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf), obuf);` на `SHA1(ibuf, strlen((const char*)ibuf), obuf);`

Гуглим [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMHEoBkxYaQ&ab_channel=TroubleChute)

На этом видео на 18:38 на экране на четверть секунды мелькает фолдер с либами, которые надо прилинковать.

Видно, что библиотека называется `libcrypto`

Перебираем все возможные файлы на диске, которые содержат это название.

На файле `llibcrypto-1_1-x64.dll` нам везет, и команда

```
    g++.exe -std=c++17 -llibcrypto-1_1-x64 -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/ -g shatest.cpp -o shatest.exe
```

успешно собирает проект.

- А как же со статической линковкой? - спросит внимательный читатель

Забудьте. Это Windows, детка. Здесь такого не бывает.

Все мои попытки как то подсунуть g++'у либу и ключ -static свелись к одной и той же ошибке `undefined reference to 'SHA1'`

2. Возвращаемся к исходной задаче. Мне user7860670 любезно подсказал, что нужно перечислить все C++ - файлы, входящие в проект.

Итак, на команде

```
    g++.exe -std=c++17  -g main.cpp CSmtp.cpp md5.cpp base64.cpp -llibcrypto-1_1-x64 -llibssl-1_1-x64 -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/ -o main.exe
```

линкер начинает ругаться совсем по-новому, и эта ругать уже относится к winsock.

Пробую добавить винсок в список зависимостей.

Мучаюсь некоторое время, подбирая имена библиотеки в -l и пути в -L - ключах компилятора. Жалуюсь на проблему в комментариях, и получаю очень ценные подсказки. я бы их высек в граните, если б мне попалась под руку подходящая плита.

I. Неправильно писать ключи -l (и, видимо, -L) слева от набора *.cpp фалов в команде для g++. Эти штуки надо писать справа.

II. Угадывание зависимостей - это, конечно, увлекательная игра, но большие мальчики просто получают эту информацию, выполнив команду (в моём случае) `pkg-config --libs --cflags --static openssl`. Эта команда выдает инфу в таком виде:

```
    pkg-config --libs --cflags --static openssl
    -IC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/include -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32
```

-и все, что нужно сделать, это просто скопировать нужные ключи и пути в команду для g++

III. Чтобы это стало возможным - нужно установить этот самый pkg-config, что в моём случае делается командой `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`, которую нужно написать в окне msys2-shell.

IIII. Статическая компиляция под windows существует! В это трудно поверить, после того, как я несколько лет не мог этого сделать и был готов откусить себе пальцы от зависти, видя, как просто это работает в той же убунте. Весь секрет, видимо, в той самой неправильной последовательности *.cpp файлов и ключей -l в команде g++...

В результате команда

```
    g++.exe -std=c++17 -static -g main.cpp CSmtp.cpp md5.cpp base64.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lcrypt32 -o main.exe
```

успешно собирает проект!

Большое спасибо всем, кто подсказывал и вообще дочитал до этого места.

Comment: *"попытки как то подсунуть g++'у либу и ключ -static свелись к одной и той же ошибке"* Попробуйте писать флажки не руками, а достать из `pkg-config`.Еще я заметил, что вы пишете в команде `-l...` слева от `.cpp`. У меня это не работало, их нужно было обязательно ставить справа. *"Это Windows, детка"* Хз, у меня проблем со статической линковкой ни разу не было (хотя OpenSSL я не использовал), кроме случаев, когда статические библиотеки как таковые не поставлялись.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - большое спасибо за совет, он пришелся очень кстати. Могу я заодно спросить еще вот что: теперь я вернулся к исходной задаче, и теперь у меня линкер находит всё, относящееся к криптографии, и ругается на простые winsock - функции. То есть, надо прилинковать windows winsock 2 в 64-битной версии. я ище её в C:\Windows\SysWOW64, но нахожу там только ws2_32.dll, в описании которой написано что это "32 bit dll"

Comment: Вроде у меня работало просто `-lws2_32` (даже для 64-битных приложений), без установки каких-то пакетов и без указания путей к dll-кам. Если winsock используется в openssl, то порядок `-lws2_32` относительно `-l` openssl может быть важен. Еще, `-LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/lib` и `-IC:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\include` по идее не должны быть нужны, оно должно само находиться.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Нет, если убрать  -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/ - линкер просто ругается на то, что не может найти библиотеку.

Comment: А это потому что вы напрямую линкуетесь с `.dll`. Если линковаться с `.dll.a`, то его он должен найти сам. Попробуйте `-lcrypto` (справа от `.cpp`) вместо `-llibcrypto-1_1-x64`, и он должен найти `/mingw64/lib/libcrypto.dll.a`. Все-таки советую не самому выискивать правильные флаги, а брать их из `pkg-config --libs --cflags --static openssl`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо, совет насчет -lcrypto (справа от .cpp) вместо -llibcrypto-1_1-x64 - помог, теперь простейшие примеры с крипто лайбрари получается собрать статически! Правда, пока непонятно, как быть с винсоком...

Comment: А `-lws2_32` не помог? `pkg-config --libs --cflags --static openssl` должен его выдавать вместе с другими флажками.

Comment: я попробовал запускать pkg-config просто из командной строки и из окна msys2-shell, но в обеих случаях такой команды в системе не оказалось. И простой поиск по строгому совпадению "*pkg-config*" на диске ничего не находит.

Comment: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config`

Comment: да, я написал комментарий, а  потмо сам догадался спросить pacman об этом. Спасибо!

Comment: Вот опять, опять я два часа бился головой о клавиатуру, пока не решил перечитать вопрос, и опять двадцать пять: эти чёртовы -l... и -L... ключи компилятора надо писать СПРАВА от перечня исходных и результирующих файлов. То есть, не 'g++ -std=c++20 -lcurl -LC:/Programs/msys64/usr/lib/ -g tst.cpp -o tst.exe', а 'g++ -std=c++20 -g tst.cpp -o tst.exe -lcurl -LC:/Programs/msys64/usr/lib/' - в случае компиляции с curl