# Непонятно куда обращать OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY и OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR

Tags: c++, telegram-bot, библиотеки, clion, library

Установил OpenSSL как было рекомендовано [на этом сайте](https://www.openssl.org/source/gitrepo.html). Ошибок никаких не выдало. Установил прямо в проект "C:/Users/P/CLionProjects/Test1/openssl".

Изначально устанавливал библиотеку для [телеграм-бота](https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp). Во время выполнения "cmake ." выпадает ошибка

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (mess
age):
  Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
  system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY
  OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_ME
SSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:570 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/P/CLionProjects/Test1/tgbot-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/P/CLionProjects/Test1/tgbot-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Куда мне в CMake отправлять OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR и OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY?

(Работаю в CLion третий раз, до этого довольствовался встроенными библиотеками, так что опыта ноль)

Comment: Дык у вас шиндоус. Используете vcpkg) к него есть cmake интеграция. Просто будет быстрее....

Comment: Если использовать vcpkg - надо как то CLion'у объяснить, что надо использовать микрософтовский компилер... я не уверен, что это простая задача.

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, что нужно проверить системную переменную OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR и OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY

Делается это в командной строке, при вызоые команды set у Вас появится список строк, среди котрых должны быть эти переменные. примерно как на вот этой картинке:

[image: как это выглядит в командной строке]

О том, как их настраивать, проще всего раскажет картинка: зайти в панельуправления -> система, далее:

[image: настройки]

Если это не решит проблему - пишите в комментариях, будем думать дальше

Comment: Проверил. Переменных небыло, добавил. Но папки openssl\lib у меня нет (как и у них на гитхабе)

Comment: openssl\lib - это папка с бинарными библиотеками... Мне кажется, Вас может выручить установка openssl через такую прекрасную штуку, как msys2. Это штука, которая снимает кучу головной боли. Фактически, установка openssl будет сводиться к тому, чтобы в окошке msys2 выполнить команду pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl. Можете прочитать мой вопрос, о том, как я мучился: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176381/

Comment: Спасибо. Большая часть ошибок исчезла, хотя OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY найти до сих пор не может при "cmake ." . Переменная стоит на C:\msys64\mingw64\lib, где есть libcrypto.dll.a (и без .dll) что кажеться и есть то что надо

Comment: А сборка из командной строки работает? в смысле - без cmake, просто вызовом компилятора? Может, проблема уже переместилась в область "как настроить cmake"?

Comment: Не знаю. (Напомню, у меня опыта очень немного) Возможно да, ибо застрял я именно на моменте Library installation(https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp)

Comment: Я промучался часа два или три. В прошлый раз, когда мне понадобилось - я смог компилировать свои программы из под винды с использованием openssl компилятором g++ из MinGW из командной строки. Вы ставите себе более сложную задачу: заставить под виндой работать cmake. Здесь - я сдаюсь. Это выше человеческих сил. Возможно, в это вопрос придет какой нибудь БОГ и расскажет нам, смертным, как это делать. Полинтернета заполнено плачем про то, что cmake под windows заставить работать просто невозможно. Может, проще сменить ОС? Под linux все работает, а на пользователей винды всем плевать.

Comment: Чуть менее эмоционально: Вы пишете, что застрали на моменте инсталляуии библиотек. Вопрос: каким компилятором Вы пользуетесь? чтобы линковка работала, и библиотеки и программа должны быть собраны одним тулсетом. под виндой есть минимум два тулсета: с++ компилятор от майкрософта и компилятор MinGW. Если Вы хотите собирать MS - компилятором, то надо копать в сторону vcpkg.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Я ещё попробовыл, а потом через vcpkg установил библиотеки, решая попутно появившиеся проблемы.

Comment: И как, собралось в результате cmak'ом? В смысле - исходная библиотека, которая для телеграмма?